# Entity framework CodeFirst: How to register new classes on the context and create them on the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, plugins

I'm considering a plug-in ready application with EntityFramework, where the user could write and deploy new plugins at runtime.

I'm using EF6 code first. The question is : Would it possible to add new classes to the DbContext and re-run the initializers to create them on the Database if they don't exist?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from version 6, the Entity Framework migrations supports multiple contexts per database. So each plug-in can have its own client context and migrate their own tables as needed.

Check
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621#multiple